# Liquid Variable not being rendered inside {% if %}

Tags: javascript, liquid

I have the following liquid code. The searchTerm variable doesn't function properly inside of the if statement. If I hard-code the if statement to something that will work, I can access the value of the searchTerm variable in the 2nd h4 you see here, so I know it's being populated.

The if statement is somehow not reading it correctly - it always evaluates to false, even if it should be true. Am I using the searchTerm variable wrong inside the if statement?

EDIT: I think the issue is that the searchTerm variable has quotation marks in the string - liquid seems to be including them somehow in the string and escaping them. When I print the searchTerm variable, it literally prints "variable" with the quotation marks included. I'm at a loss for how to remove them, because I don't know how to escape them so I can reference them properly in liquid.

```
{% assign searchTerm = request.params['term'] %}

{% if firstName contains searchTerm %}
 <item>
  <h4> {{item.usc_firstname}} </h4>
  <h4> {{searchTerm}} </h4>
  <hr width = "100%">
 </item>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Where is firstname coming from? You're showing searchTerm, but not firstname.

Comment: Hey Mike, yea it's coming from an application. No problems with that.

Comment: So what are the values of searchTerm and firstName when it doesn't work?

Comment: Just added an edit - I think it's an issue with quotation marks in searchTerm. Not sure why they're there. An instance where it doesn't work is where firstName = drew and searchTerm = "drew" (with the quotation marks literally included).

Comment: Are you including the quotes in your URL? In other words, what is the raw value of term that you're sending?

Comment: Yes - the URL string did have quotes around the parameter. That's probably the problem!

Comment: Yep - that's the problem. If I can remove them from the parameter, then the if statement works. Throw that in the answer if you'd like and I'll mark it answered. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're sending in as `term` may have quotes around it. Make sure it doesn't as the quotes will be included in the literal value for `searchTerm`. :)

Comment: That's the problem Mike - I had quotation marks in my query string parameter, and it was getting passed into the liquid variable, where I didn't know how to escape them. Thanks for your help!